# NMake - "Clean Command Line" property on clean build/rebuild

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, nmake

I have a NMake project that has command property set in "Clean Command Line"
to delete everything in the project's `/Release` folder.

I am using TFS' option for **clean** build which executes `/t:clean` as MSBuild parameter.

The problem is when TFS first tries to delete the content of the `/Release` folder, there is no such folder nor files and it errors out and breaks the build.

Is there something I could use in order to pass this error without breaking the build or a way to check if the folder exist or doesn't so it could pass or delete the content?

Thank you!

EDIT: On project's properties there's a tag `<NMakeCleanCommandLine>` that has Condition parameter, but I don't know how to work with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually managed to resolve this issue by checking from the project properties `Clean Command Line` parameter if the `\Release` folder exist, using `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` as relative path.

The command then is:

`IF EXIST "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Release\" del "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Release\*.*"`

one could decide to use `$(Configuration)` instead of `\Release` in order to target build configurations.

Comment: To be precise, use:

`IF EXIST "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)" del "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)"`

Answer (score 0):

On TFS side, you could add a [Powersell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=vsts) before the clean task, to check whether the `/Release` folder exists, if it exists, then run clean task, if it doesn't exists, skip clean task.

Comment: Thanx for getting back to me! 
I have actually managed to resolve this issue by checking from the project properties Clean Command Line for the release folder, using `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` as relative path.. the command is:

`IF EXIST "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Release\" del "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Release\*.*"`

one could decide to use `$(Configuration)\$(Platform)"` in order to cover different project build configuration options

Comment: Clean build is an option TFS provides but I think it is related to post-build clean, on the other hand MSBuild step has argument /t:clean /t:rebuild, therefore the solution I came up with above seems more suitable, thanks again!